# On $[0,1]$ with the Lesbegue measure, is it possible to have $\lVert \cdot \rVert^{1/n}_p \leq \lVert \cdot \rVert_q$ for $p>q$ and $n$ large?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

The question is as in the above.

In all literature, I only find that on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, $\lVert \cdot \rVert_q \leq \lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ for $p>q$.

(I deleted the last question because it was poorly worded...) but in the last question, what I wanted to know is the possibility of reversing this inequality.

Namely, for a given pair $p>q$ and all $f \in L^q[0,1]$ with $\lVert f \rVert_q \geq 1$, is it possible to have some very large but "fixed" $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_p^{1/n} \leq \lVert f \rVert_q
\end{equation}

Comment: No.  Take $f = \varepsilon^{-1/q} 1_{[0,\varepsilon]}$ for a small $\varepsilon>0$.  (More generally, step functions tend to be excellent test cases for these sorts of inequalities.)

Comment: Oh, I see. What if I change the condition to $\lVert f \rVert_q >1$ instead?

Comment: Now take $f = 2\varepsilon^{-1/q} 1_{[0,\varepsilon]}$.